# How to do face recognition in background in python?

Tags: python, opencv, python-multithreading, face-recognition

##### Problem I am Facing

I am new to python and I want to do face recognition on the footage of webcam. So, I am using below code to achieve the task I want. I got it from youtube. My laptop has intel i7 7th gen, 4 core processor and 8 GB RAM, 4 GB graphics card (AMD R7 M445). When I start streaming I only get  20 fps even if my camera is capable of transmitting 30fps. On top of that when there is a person in frame, stream gets extremely unusable and it gets lower fps like 0.5 and even 0.2 fps.

##### My theory

So, I am guessing that this is a linear and pretty basic program. So, all the tasks including streaming and face recognition is being done on the same thread. That is why fps is getting delayed.

##### Solution I want

So, I want to create a structure where the face recognition will be done on a background thread and streaming will be displayed by on going foreground thread.

I still don't understand why my pc is displaying streaming at 20fps and not in 30fps.

**Updated Code (Added perf_counter and added user defined functions)**

Please refer to below link for old code.

[Old py code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qkpIwkVNddMLx_tB-hJDMi8IKKd2QNeU/view?usp=sharing)

```
import cv2
from simple_facerec import SimpleFacerec
from datetime import datetime

from time import perf_counter


prev = 0
count = 0
vid_cod = ""
cap = ""
path =""
vid_name = ""
output = ""
sfr = ""


def vidCapture():
    global cap,prev,count,sfr

    while (cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        
        # Detect Faces
        startDetect = perf_counter()
        face_locations, face_names = sfr.detect_known_faces(frame)
        for face_loc, name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
            y1, x2, y2, x1 = face_loc[0], face_loc[1], face_loc[2], face_loc[3]

            #if the face is recognised then 
            if name != "Unknown" :
                print("known Person detected :) => " + name)
                stopDetect = perf_counter()
                print(f"Time taken to identify face : {stopDetect-startDetect}")


            #else if the face is unknown then 
            else :
                stopDetect = perf_counter()
                print(f"Time taken to identify face : {stopDetect-startDetect}")
                print("Unknown Person detected :( => Frame captured...")

        #show the frames on the display
        cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

        #write frames to output object so it can save the video
        output.write(frame)


        #to terminate the process press "x"
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0XFF == ord('x'):
            break

    cap.release()
    output.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


def __init__():

    global prev,count,vid_cod,vid_name,cap,path,output,sfr
    startSfr = perf_counter()
    # Encode faces from a folder
    sfr = SimpleFacerec()
    sfr.load_encoding_images("images/")
    stopSfr = perf_counter()

    loadSfr = stopSfr-startSfr
    print(f"Time taken to load sfr : {loadSfr}")

    startCam = perf_counter()
    # Load Camera
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('https://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/videofeed')
    #cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    stopCam = perf_counter()

    loadCam = stopCam-startCam

    print(f"Time taken to load cam : {loadCam}")

    startCodec = perf_counter()
    #Use MPEG video codec
    vid_cod = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MPEG')
    stopCodec = perf_counter()

    loadCodec = stopCodec-startCodec
    print(f"Time taken to load codec : {loadCodec}")


    startInit = perf_counter()
    prev = 0
    count = 0
    #defining the path where video will be saved
    path = 'C:/Users/Username/Documents/Recorded/'

    #Encode video name with date and time
    vid_name = str("recording_"+datetime.now().strftime("%b-%d-%Y_%H:%M").replace(":","_")+".avi")

    #initialize video saving process as a "output" object
    output = cv2.VideoWriter( str(path+vid_name) , vid_cod, 20.0 ,(640,480))
    stopInit = perf_counter()

    loadInit = stopInit - startInit
    print(f"Time taken to load rest : {loadInit}")
    vidCapture()

__init__()
```

This below file is simplefacerec which is imported in the above code.

[simple_facerec.py](https://drive.google.com/file/d/104CiwSee2zQfkXYkffkkk3c_kSDyfgAt/view?usp=sharing)

**Note:**

When I change fps in `output` from 20 to 25, saved video length gets decreased and when I change fps from 20 to 15 then video length gets increased. This is how I got the streaming fps of a video.

##### My Logs

After putting `perf_counter()` I found that face recognition alone is taking about 0.5 seconds. This whole code ran for about 7 to 8 seconds in which only 5 frames were displayed.

```
Time taken to load sfr : 2.3252885000001697
Time taken to load cam : 0.3193597999998019
Time taken to load codec : 1.3199998647905886e-05
Time taken to load rest : 0.0018557999974291306
known Person detected :) => Anirudhdhsinh Jadeja
Time taken to identify face : 0.4715902999996615
known Person detected :) => Anirudhdhsinh Jadeja
Time taken to identify face : 0.5326913999997487
known Person detected :) => Anirudhdhsinh Jadeja
Time taken to identify face : 0.4969602000019222
known Person detected :) => Anirudhdhsinh Jadeja
Time taken to identify face : 0.4868558000016492
known Person detected :) => Anirudhdhsinh Jadeja
Time taken to identify face : 0.4679383000002417
```

Comment: find out what's taking so long. profile the code, or use `time.perf_counter()` to measure sections of the code. -- my guess is the recognition is DNN-based so it's expensive.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I don't know the python too much. So, I just copy pasted the code from youtube to understand it by my self. So, I don't know if the recognition is DNN based or not. But, I did add `time.perf_counter()` and updated the question. My problem is how to produce actually usable footage..